# Magento js file 404 error after some working on project (tinycolor)

Tags: magento2, javascript, 404, static-content, static-content-deploy

I use Magento 2.2.1 . After some working on project and adding modules, all things were right until I go to the category page. It gives me error with subject tinycolor.js 404 file not found on console log:
[image]

I have tried all commands for reproducing static files but this case (tinycolor.js)  was not produced. (I went to the mentioned URL directory but I didn't see any tinycolor.js file) how to solve this forever?

Answer (score -1):

You said this - `I went to the mentioned URL directory but I didn't see any tinycolor.js file` . Now at this location you should manually do copy the tinycolor.js file by your self, then do the `bin/magento c:f` command and do the inspect element again to see if your file is still there. I hope it will fix the issue.